# JSESSIONID across subdomains

Tags: java, session, cookies, jboss, subdomain

I'm trying to have my JSESSIONID at ".mysite.com" so it can be shared across subdomains.

I have a 4.2.2 GA JBOSS instance doing this with this method: http://shchekoldin.com/2010/05/27/sharing-jsessionid-across-subdomains/ (which is from here: https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBWEB-107) using the custom valve approach.

However on the EAP 5.1 version (I've compiled against JDK 1.6) the same custom valve doesn't kick in. I added some debugging but it never gets called.

Also, I tried turning on the SSO option in server.xml (as per https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWebSingleSignOn) through the non-clustered method, but this plays no impact on it either.

Does anyone know how I can the JSESSIONID cookie to sit across subdomains on JBOSS 5?

(Side note, if I have "foo.bar.mysite.com" will this ".mysite.com" domain stored against the cookie work for multiple sub domains - this is for testing, in prod we just have the one level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed:

You add `<SessionCookie domain="example.com"/>` under  in the WEB-INF/context.xml of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same requirement. Share session across sites having sub-domain and parent domain within same .war file. e.g www.baseball.sports.com and www.hockey.sports.com. 
To share JSESSION b/w these two sites need to add domain tag in jboss-web.xml.

File path : /app/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/mason_production/.ear/.war/WEB-INF.

Add below entries :

.sports.com

Comment: Adding a link to the reference documentation can help users reading your answer get more details.